# C# ConcurrentDictionary - Best practice and method for wildcard key search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, collections, wildcard, key-value

I have a `ConcurrentDictionary` of `string`  (key) and `object` (value).
I want to have an if statement that returns true if any key in my dictionary contains the sub-string 'xyz'.
Better yet, if it begins with 'xyz'.
Is there any way to do this?

I tried using `concurrentDict.Keys.Contains` & `concurrentDict.ContainsKey`.
Both do not serve the purpose.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this?

```
    return dictionary.Any(item => item.Key.StartsWith("xyz"));
```